# Code formatting in org-mode headlines on export to PDF

Tags: org-mode, org-export

You can use formatting in headlines in `org-mode`. For example:

```
* Behavior of the _insert_ operation
```

This exports to PDF just fine.

If, however, your formatting is code formatting

```
* Behavior of the ~insert~ operation
```

, exporting it PDF results in an error message instead of a PDF:

```
org-latex-compile: PDF file built_files_ignored_by_git_tex/a.pdf wasn't produced: [undefined control sequence] Runaway argument
```

Within Emacs, the formatting is displayed correctly.

Is this a bug? Is there something a user can do to make the PDF build correctly?

I use GNU Emacs 24.5.1 and (according to what's written to the `pdfcreator` tag in the exported LaTeX document) org-mode `8.2.10`.

Comment: Your example exports to LaTeX as `\section{Behavior of the \texttt{insert} operation}`, and export to PDF works fine here. How does your export to LaTeX look like? EDIT: This should include any header arguments or other LaTeX code as `Runaway argument` usually indicates a missing closed bracket.

Comment: For me, it exports to `\section{Behavior of the \verb~insert~ operation}`. I added the version of Emacs I use to the question. Here is the entire LaTeX file created on export: https://pastebin.com/9rreiGNz I substituted my name by `<my name>`. Everything else is unchanged.

Comment: Your example doesn't compile for me, the culprit being `\verb`. Somehow `pdflatex` doesn't recognize the `~` as the separators and interprets them as a command. Can you upgrade your version of org to a more recent one? The exporter now seems to favour `\texttt` now.

Comment: It worked! Thank you! Want to post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade your version of org-mode. Recent versions use `\texttt` instead of `\verb`. `\verb` allows you to choose a separator such as `+` or `|` to denote the text part. While `~` should also work, here it does not.